# how should hold session when closed browser?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I used this code in .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime "3600"
```

and use this function for renew timeout session :

```
private function renewCusTimeout(){
        $_SESSION["customer"]["usertimeout"]=time();
    }
```

but it's have problem because i set session for example one hour when their login and when customer surfing and doing every thing in my web site that time extended and renew.
but cookie can't renew time .and when first 3600 seconds was spent then customer logout .

It's problem is `session.cookie_lifetime` in .htaccess not extended the time when customer surfing and it's only set time when login.

how can extended `session.cookie_lifetime` time when customer yet login and doing every thing ?

Comment: Wow, it's quite hard to understand what you're asking. Just 2 things : 1) Keeping the session if the browser is closed is not possible. 3) Session timeout is generally considered on idle time : 3600 seconds is 1 hour idle time before the session is discarded. if user stays active , the session could last for hours, or even days

Comment: I edited the post , and dear Bartdude you can use session.cookie_lifetime for hold session when customer closed browser . i test it and it's correctly work

Comment: Indeed I was wrong, but from a security perspective I find it dangerous to use it. That's what lead me to the wrong remark : I never use this and never wanted to use it. As a user, talking of session cookies, I expect them to be deleted when I close my browser (although any user cautious about security should always use the log out functionality)

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a session last when a browser closes. That's sort of the whole point of sessions. Try cookies instead. Also, timeout is measured in idle time; i.e. when the user isn't doing anything. So changing the value in `.htaccess` won't affect it. Read about cookies [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php).

Comment: you can use session.cookie_lifetime for hold session when customer closed browser . i test it and it's correctly work